# Catch a TimeoutError of a promise beforehand

Tags: timeout, promise, bluebird

I have a bluebird promise which can be cancelled. When cancelled, I have to do some work to neatly abort the running task. A task can be cancelled in two ways: via `promise.cancel()` or `promise.timeout(delay)`.

In order to be able to neatly abort the task when cancelled or timed out, I have to catch CancellationErrors and TimeoutErrors. Catching a CancellationError works, but for some reason I can't catch a TimeoutError:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function task() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // ... a long running task ...
      })
      .cancellable()
      .catch(Promise.CancellationError, function(error) {
        // ... must neatly abort the task ...
        console.log('Task cancelled', error);
      })
      .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function(error) {
        // ... must neatly abort the task ...
        console.log('Task timed out', error);
      });
}

var promise = task();

//promise.cancel(); // this works fine, CancellationError is caught

promise.timeout(1000); // PROBLEM: this TimeoutError isn't caught!
```

How can I catch timeout errors *before* a timeout is set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you cancel a promise, the cancellation first bubbles to its parents as long as a parents are found that are still cancellable, this is very different from normal rejection which only propagates to children.

`.timeout` does a simple normal rejection, it doesn't do cancellation, so that's why it's not possible to do it like this.

You can either cancel after a delay:

```js
var promise = task();
Promise.delay(1000).then(function() { promise.cancel(); });
```

or set the timeout in the task function:

```js
var promise = task(1000);

function task(timeout) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // ... a long running task ...
      })
      .timeout(timeout)
      .cancellable()
      .catch(Promise.CancellationError, function(error) {
        // ... must neatly abort the task ...
        console.log('Task cancelled', error);
      })
      .catch(Promise.TimeoutError, function(error) {
        // ... must neatly abort the task ...
        console.log('Task timed out', error);
      });
}
```

---

You can also create a method like:

```js
Promise.prototype.cancelAfter = function(ms) {
  var self = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    self.cancel();
  }, ms);
  return this;
};
```

Then

```js
function task() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // ... a long running task ...
      })
      .cancellable()
      .catch(Promise.CancellationError, function(error) {
        // ... must neatly abort the task ...
        console.log('Task cancelled', error);
      })
}

var promise = task();

// Since it's a cancellation, it will propagate upwards so you can
// clean up in the task function
promise.cancelAfter(1000);
```

Comment: Thanks, I expected something like that. Problem is that I can't ask the user to neatly run promise.cancel() after using a timeout on a promise returned by my code. In that case the only option I see is to let the user specify an (optional) timeout when creating the task, like `promise = task([timeout])`, rather then doing a `promise.timeout(delay)` afterwards.

Comment: @JosdeJong hmm I saw you posted on getify's blog that you still have this problem - I would simply define a new method on the Promise prototype, see my edit

Comment: Hi Esailija, thanks for getting back to me. Your `cancelAfter` function is indeed exactly what I was looking for rather than bluebirds `timeout`. I'm not a fan of messing with global prototypes though. I think Kyle has some good points. There is a serious difference between the controllable task I am looking for (non-chainable), and a generic Promise which can be chained and forked etc. It makes sense to me to wrap the control functionality I need in a Task prototype, internally using promises. The Task is then both a Promise and a PromiseResolver.

Comment: @JosdeJong it's not a global prototype, read this https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#for-library-authors

Comment: Yes that's true, so this problem is perfectly solvable with bluebird.  Still, a solution with a simple ES6 Promise polyfill + a thin Task wrapper looks better to me. Easy to explain and maintain, a clear separation of concerns, and no lock-in to a specific Promise implementation.

Comment: @JosdeJong I don't get it, aren't you already using bluebird? Btw `timeout` method will have more useful behavior in 2.0: it will cancel the promise with a `TimeoutError` (also cancel takes an argument for custom rejection reason).

Comment: That is good news, that means that in bluebird v2.0 the `Promise.timeout` actually works as I initially expected :). Bluebird is great and extremely flexible but also a little bloated. I use it with pleasure in several projects. This particular project is in early stage and I'm looking around for the "best" solution.

Comment: @JosdeJong yep here's the commit https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/commit/b0dd9191cb427b38aeb54ca01748b8da89d01c4c :). Some lot of bloat will be removed in 2.0 (see [WIP 2.0 docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/iterators/API.md)) and I plan to remove some completely useless features [like progression](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/iterators/API.md#progression).